# Stack Snippets Returning a 503 Service Unavailable Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Not sure if it's just me but Stack Snippets seems to be down

E.g. http://stacksnippets.net/

```html
Hi
```

Comment: 503, yep, it's down. SRE should already know about it, I'll check to make sure.

Comment: Working for me…

Comment: Fix deployed. SRE will write something up if this was anything more interesting than a blip.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks that was quick

Comment: Not working for me until this moment.

Comment: @Tim Post: I'm still getting HTTP 503 errors. Very strangely, this only happens with my home Internet and not mobile data (i.e. snippets load just fine on data). Should I post new?

Comment: This was referenced here: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5778/132

Comment: @TimPost Still not working ... from Norway

Comment: @TimPost I posted my tracert here if it can be to any help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343548/stack-snippets-not-working

Comment: @TimPost Appears to be [solved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343548/stack-snippets-not-working#comment446348_343548) and works for me now

Comment: From BR, I was having the same problem, it worked for me now.