# Snippet HTTP Error 503: service unavailable

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Basically the same as this one : [Stack Snippets Returning a 503 Service Unavailable Error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343509)

Quite annoying. Tried with both firefox and chrome.

(Sorry if it's a duplicate)

A question with snippets for the example : [clear data from a row in a table html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226400)

### Edit:

Fixed. I'm not even trying to understand.

Comment: Same for me ...

Comment: I'm not even trying to understand how it's fixed.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer I guess someone broke something, and then someone fixed it :)

Comment: No idea, but the SREs were working on firewalls yesterday, so... Maybe something with that.